# Background overrides my jumbotron in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code:

```
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img style="max-width:100px; margin-top: -7px;" src="images/firma-Edgar-Ayales.png" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <!--End navbar-header-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Feedback</a>
            <li><a href="#features">Gallery</a>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Features</a>
            <li><a href="#feedback">Faq</a>
            <li><a href="#contact">ContactUs</a>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- End container -->
</nav><!-- End navbar -->

<div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
      <h1>Transformamos tus ideas en atractivos diseños</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

The text is getting behind the background. I want the first part of my webpage to be a background, including the navbar. CSS is:

```
.navbar {
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   font-size: 10pt;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
   color: white;
   font-family: "Tahoma", sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
}

#my-navbar {
   background: url(images/bgfix.jpg) no-repeat;
   height: 700px;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   position: absolute;
}

#titulobg {
   text-align: center;
   padding-top: 450px;
   color: black;
   font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

.jumbotron {
   color: white;
   text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
   background: transparent;
}
```

Also when I try to add a new div to add a text it goes behind the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are extending "my-navbar" from "navbar". Which inherits all of navbar's properties, including a high z-index. The z-index just tells the browser what overlaps what. Low z-index's is used for the background and high z-index's are used for the foreground.

```
#my-navbar{
    background:url(images/bgfix.jpg) no-repeat; 
        height: 700px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

**EDIT:**
With a relative position

```
#my-navbar{
        background:url(images/bgfix.jpg) no-repeat; 
            height: 700px;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            position: relative;
            z-index: -1;
        }
```

**EDIT 2:** To remove the annoying white absolute bar at the top.

```
body {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: And now, what can I do if I want to add a new section just after the background without overriding it?

Comment: I might be reading this wrong but... You have 3 sections, navbar, my-navbar, newSection and you wan't the new section to not overlap my-navbar. The solution to this would be to set newSection's z-index to lower than your background's, so -2 for example. Again, I might of read that wrong...

Comment: I've just explained myself wrong. I mean, adding a new div container with a p will just add the paragraph inside the background, and I want to add the paragraph or whatever my div contains after the background so I can keep designing my website, for example to add a "Projects" section.

Comment: I can tell you the problem has to do with the css "position" attribute. It would be hard to say how to fix it without more code but it might be as easy as setting #my-navbar's position to "relative".

Comment: I've tried adding the relative, but a white frame appears in top of the navbar, no idea why. But yes, you solved my question.

Comment: That's probably a bootstrap thing to stop your absolute navbar from hiding  the top of your webpage. You might be able to right click and inspect element to find a way to remove it.

Comment: The problem is the body tag, do I have to move the navbar into the head tag?

Comment: No, the Head tag is reserved for meta information such as scripts/css/etc.

I'm unsure how to remove it though. I do remember running into this problem myself a while back. Might be worth another question.

Or if you have it hosted anywhere I could give it a glance.

Comment: Try adding body { padding-top: 0; }

Comment: It didn't work so I started a new question, thanks for your help sir.